# Redirect everything to one file, disallow direct access to PHP files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with creating a set of rules in my .htaccess file, resulting in constant 500 Internal Server Errors instead.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /router.php?rq=$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /router.php?rq=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want my .htaccess to behave like this:

1. All requests (except resources, images, CSS, js, etc) should
   redirect to /router.php, preserving query strings. I don't need the
   REQUEST_URI as a query string as it is available via
   `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` regardless.
2. All attempts to access a PHP file directly, for example user enters
   "index.php", should also redirect to router.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule for your routing:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/router\.php [NC]
RewriteRule \.php$ /router.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /router.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: That works, but it still goes to a certain PHP file in case it exists. For example, if I enter `/test.php` (an existing file) it loads that file, not `router.php`

Comment: Really? It shouldn't happen and I had tested that condition explicitly before posting. But I will break this rule into 2 to force it.

Comment: Thanks, but this now gives me a 500 Internal Error, regardless of URL I load )=

Comment: That is really weird because I tested it again and found it working. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess OR any other .htaccess in your system.

Comment: Also let me know if you're using any CMS/PHP framework

Comment: I'm using WAMP, only thing I have before your rules is `php_value auto_prepend_file "E:/wamp/www/alert/_classes/__config.php"`

Comment: Ok can you comment out `php_value` line for testing. Also can you check your error.log to see what is reason of this 500 error.

Comment: `AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.` is the error I get in the logs, commenting out php_value did no difference

Comment: Are `router.php` and `.htaccess` both placed in DOCUMENT_ROOT or in some sub-directory? Also I made an edit, can you try this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43274/discussion-between-silkfire-and-anubhava)